# Getting a selection from multiple tables using JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a task: Display the hourly rates of employees, indicating the maximum rate for each department in the column Max In Department. Within each department, divide all bets into groups so that bets with the same values are part of the same group.

I wrote a request to get a breakdown of bids into groups in departments, and I ran into the problem that the maximum bid in the department is calculated by the column with the breakdown of the bid per group, but it is necessary by departments, I tried both through a separate request and a connection with this and through a nested query, I can't understand what I'm doing wrong

I will be grateful for any help!

```
  SELECT Name AS DepartmentName
       , Rate AS GroupOfRate
       , MAX(eph.Rate) AS MaxRateInDepartment
    FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory edh
         INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department d
                 ON edh.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
         INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory eph
                 ON edh.BusinessEntityID = eph.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY Name
       , Rate
```

The first photo is the result of my request with an error. The second photo, the tables on which the selection is made (1 table EmployeePayHistory, where the employee rates are located; 2 table EmployeeDepartmentHistory; 3 table just take the names of departments). The third photo, as it should turn out (made in Paint)

[Photo #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG5fq.png)
[Photo #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfKdu.jpg)
[Photo #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qkel.png)

Comment: Tip of today: make it easy to assist you! Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images or links to images.

Comment: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ can be used for Ascii Tables

Comment: It's also helpful to read https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Comment: ... Tip of the day 2:  If you're using a commonly known sample database like "AdventureWorks", please say so in your question :) Sites like [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) already include that database, so you can easily create a "fiddle" to demonstrate your query and results. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=ab849279eab7074d82d3eac08c5f2a7b  .  Use the "markdown" link to generate nicely formatted code and tables you can paste directly here.

Comment: Also since this sounds like a homework question, see: How do I ask Homework Questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to add a partition.

```
  SELECT Name AS DepartmentName
       , Rate AS GroupOfRate
       , MAX(eph.Rate) OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name ) AS MaxRateInDepartment
    FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory edh
         INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department d
                 ON edh.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
         INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory eph
                 ON edh.BusinessEntityID = eph.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY Name
       , Rate
```

By grouping by rate, you're restricting your `MAX` to Department Name and Rate. The `OVER` clause frees it up to look only at the department name.

You can confirm by adding an `ORDER BY` clause to the query.

```
ORDER BY Name
       , Rate
```

This should show that the first row for each department matches the department maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Your `GROUP BY Name, Rate` clause will create separate groups for each distinct department name and rate, which means every rate within that group will be the same. That is why Max(Rate) is giving you the same value as Rate.

If you need to display individual rates and "max rate per department" on the same line, you can use a window function. SQL window functions can be thought of as defining their own scope separate from GROUP BY. In your case you want to drop the GROUP BY and calculate the MAX rate partitioned by department.

Search for "SQL window function" for more information, syntax, and examples.